x509: certificate signed by unknown authority Minikube cluster
I deployed a single node minikube cluster with minikube start --vm-driver=none means running on the bare metal which is a VM. I deploy my own custom scheduler and after running that scheduler I am facing this error
  k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get "https://172.2.X.X:8443/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

I looked in to this issue which have same issue approximately but I did not find the solution from it. I know that the error is due to Kube API not able to authorize the request from the scheduler? but I didnt change much on the default kube-schduler.yaml file just add my image etc, but it gives error when I run mine schduelr. The kube-schduler.yaml is
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-scheduler
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-scheduler
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --leader-elect=false
    - --master=https://172.2.X.X:8443
    - --config=/etc/kubernetes/pid-config.yaml
    - --v=4
    image: localhost:5000/scheduler-plugins/kube-scheduler:latest
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10259
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-scheduler
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10259
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      name: kubeconfig
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pid-config.yaml
      name: pid-config
      readOnly: true
    env:
    - name: KUBERNETES_MASTER
      value: "https://172.2.X.X:8443"
  hostNetwork: true
  priority: 2000001000
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: kubeconfig
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pid-config.yaml
      type: File
    name: pid-config
status: {}

But when I curl the link it do accessable
curl --cacert /var/lib/minikube/certs/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://172.2.X.X:8443/api/v1/nodes -v
*   Trying 172.2.X.X:8443...
* Connected to 172.2.X.X (172.2.X.X) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /var/lib/minikube/certs/ca.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=system:masters; CN=minikube
*  start date: Apr 28 10:05:25 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 29 10:05:25 2027 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "172.22.174.151" matched cert's IP address!
*  issuer: CN=minikubeCA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x60b3af5afeb0)
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
> GET /api/v1/nodes HTTP/2
> Host: 172.2.X.X:8443
> user-agent: curl/7.81.0
> accept: */*
> authorization: Bearer 
> 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
< HTTP/2 403 
< audit-id: a5478c3b-3e6d-4139-9f2a-0219b9834622
< cache-control: no-cache, private
< content-type: application/json
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-kubernetes-pf-flowschema-uid: 12d224eb-22db-4478-8338-bbda45f8da9f
< x-kubernetes-pf-prioritylevel-uid: 3c8f01f4-c7e2-4dbe-bf72-29ad82e99dfc
< content-length: 297
< date: Wed, 01 May 2024 14:23:42 GMT
< 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "nodes is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list resource \"nodes\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "nodes"
  },
  "code": 403
* Connection #0 to host 172.2.x.x left intact

Anyone had face this error before, or any clue for the right direction to look at?
Thank you
